# Applying Gradle Dependency-Check plugin

Tags: maven, plugins, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I am trying to use the dependency.check from the following link and have been unable to get it to run properly (at all) when following the instructions given.

https://github.com/jeremylong/DependencyCheck/tree/master/dependency-check-gradle

When trying to build with the apply plugin and additional dependency the fails on startup and it throws the following error.

> - Where:
>     Build file '/Users/aaron/work/backups/eiss/build.gradle' line: 25
> - What went wrong:
>     A problem occurred evaluating root project 'eiss'.
>     Failed to apply plugin [id 'dependency.check']
>     Plugin with id 'dependency.check' not found.

I made a little progress when making some changes but was still ultimately unsuccessful.

First, I commented out the apply plugin line.

Next, I switched:

`classpath "com.thoughtworks.tools:dependency-check:0.0.7"`

over to:

`compile "com.thoughtworks.tools:dependency-check:0.0.7"`

After these two changes it began recognizing the path and I was able to see it grabbing the items from the repository.

Even with the path correct I am still having issues with the apply plugin line with it throwing the same error whenever I place it into the script or even try to change the '.' in it into a '-' (both are used in the instructions and in different repository examples).

Any help on this issue would be appreciated! Thanks

lastly here is the build.gradle script. I didn't want to just leave this blob right in the center of the post.

```
defaultTasks 'assemble'


// For third party libs that are widely used, keep versions in one place
ext {
    MONGO_JAVA_DRIVER = "org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:2.12.3"
    RABBITMQ_VERSION = "com.rabbitmq:amqp-client:3.4.3"
    LOG4J = "log4j:log4j:1.2.16"

// For groovy there are multiple libs, just capture version number and use lib-name-$GROOVY_VERSION
    GROOVY_VERSION = "2.3.6"
}

// 
// Common settings for all projects
//

subprojects {

defaultTasks 'assemble'

apply plugin: 'groovy'    
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'codenarc'
apply plugin: 'dependency.check'

targetCompatibility = "1.6"
sourceCompatibility = "1.6"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile  LOG4J
    compile "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:${GROOVY_VERSION}"
    compile "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-json:${GROOVY_VERSION}"
    compile "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-templates:${GROOVY_VERSION}"
    compile "com.thoughtworks.tools:dependency-check:0.0.7"

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
    testCompile "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-test:${GROOVY_VERSION}"
    testCompile "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3"


}



clean.doLast {
    // The archive path is configured via the jar tasks. Can't use 
    // delete jar.archivePath because that will configure the delete with
    // the wrong (default) path of build/libs/<component.jar>
    jar.archivePath.delete()
    jarSources.archivePath.delete()
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------
// Run and test
//--------------------------------------------------------------------

test {
    // Uncomment to see standard output when running tests
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
    // This causes tests to run even when nothing has changed
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
    maxParallelForks = 1
}

task runClass(dependsOn: 'classes', type: JavaExec) {
    if (project.hasProperty('classToRun')) {
        if (project.hasProperty('arguments')) {
            args(arguments.split(','))
        }
        classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
        main=classToRun
    }
}

//run this task to create source jars
task jarSources(type:Jar){
    destinationDir = new File(projectDir.parent + "/sourcelibs")
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
    classifier 'sources'         
}

}
```

Comment: You have to add the plugin depenencies in the root project's buildscript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You added plugin dependency in a wrong place, to the dependencies of your project, not a build script itself, which will use it. Try to add buildscript dependencies, as it's made in the example of plugin installation

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.thoughtworks.tools:dependency-check:0.0.7'
    }
}
```

And then return your apply plugin

```
apply plugin: 'dependency.check'
```

Comment: Alrighty,

I will give this a shot and will get back as soon as I think I have it implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Though this is very old post, accepted answer is using legacy plugin application, whereas below could be used while using the plugins DSL: https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.owasp.dependencycheck

```
plugins {
  id "org.owasp.dependencycheck" version "7.3.0"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With recent version of gradle it is below steps

add `id 'com.diffplug.spotless' version '6.3.0'` in `plugins` section like

```
plugins {
id 'com.diffplug.spotless' version '6.3.0'
}
```

And define your task to generate required format reports. Here for e.g. xml and json will be generated along with the html report

```
dependencyCheck{
    formats=['xml','json']
    check.dependsOn(dependencyCheckAnalyze)
}
```

And this can be integrated with Sonar by adding below properties to sonare.properties file (Provide dependency plugin is installed already on the sonar)

```
sonar.dependencyCheck.xmlReportPath=build/reports/dependency-check-report.xml
sonar.dependencyCheck.jsonReportPath=build/reports/dependency-check-report.json
sonar.dependencyCheck.htmlReportPath=build/reports/dependency-check-report.html
```